# Charging Li-ion with BMS but no balancer connector

Tags: lithium-ion, bms

Is there a safe way of charging a 5S1P Li-ion pack with BMS but no balancer connection?
I have a IMAX B6 charger, but it only allows charging Li-ion with balancer connection.
Could I use the Pb charger on this, as it has a BMS to cater for any overcharging?

Comment: So, if it has a BMS built in, what does the BMS do then, if it does not balance the cells? This is also more an electronic device usage question than an electrical engineering question.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing

Comment: The problem is that your battery pack and charger are not compatible. The pack would manage balancing with internally, and the charger wants to be connected to a pack without BMS as it wants to handle the balancing. And since the BMS is not a charger, it is the last line of protection which protects the cells from abuse, so no, do not connect the pack to a Pb charger.

Comment: OK, thanks. Last question. How do I charge the 5S1P pack of LI-ion batteries, as it doesn't have a balancing connector?

Comment: Look up the datasheet / instructions for the BMS that's built into your battery pack, and follow those instructions. To do anything else is asking for a dead battery at best, a burnt-down house at worst. It may or may not balance the cells. It may or may not prevent overcharge. It may or may not prevent over discharge. Do not make assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a safe way of charging a 5S1P Li-ion pack with BMS but no balancer connection?

As the battery pack has a BMS, that BMS has a balancing function. Therefore, it does not need an external balance connector. You simply charge the battery through its B+ and B- terminals.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of unbalanced charging, which easily causes cell damage and *may* cause a cell to burst, is exacerbated by the number of cells in series.  I.e. the number before the "S".

In your case you have FIVE cells in series which is virtually impossible to charge without a balancer.  So there is nothing to prevent one or more of the cells from over/under charging which will eventually cause a problem with your battery.

Do NOT use a lead-acid charger on any Li-based cell!  The charging voltages and characteristics are completely different and at best it will not work and at worst it will cause a cell to burst.

Comment: Thanks for that, however I thought the BMS stopped the charger from overcharging, or have I got it completely wrong?

Comment: I assume you mean the "Pb BMS" you mentioned.  This charger will have different settings for the lead-acid battery.  Li-ion batteries have very different characteristics.  There are some multi-chemistry chargers but these will have a switch or a menu to select the battery type.

Comment: Hi The pack is a Li-ion pack with a Li-ion BMS.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using my B6 balancing charger on one of my 12.6v 3s BMS protected Li-Ion. I get a "Connection Break" message. There is no break. I assume some BMS's aren't compatible. Or maybe it's a bad BMS. The battery itself works to run 12v devices. The B6 works fine on my other batteries with a different BMS.